# NuxtJS - Style are not found or lost

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I use **NuxtJS** for **SSR** (*Server Side Rendering*) and on my page /auth/login, styles aren't found.

I have the styles loaded in the configuration.

**nuxt.config.js:**

```
css: [
  '~assets/css/main.css',
  'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
  'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote wrong URL syntax:

Fix:

```
css: [
  '~/assets/css/main.css',
  'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
  'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
]
```